# Very strange alarm test sound that occurs every 34 minutes (video)

Tags: noise, alarm, sounds

There's a very strange test/alarm sound that occurs every 34 minutes. I checked the smoke alarms and replaced the batteries so it's not coming from those.

It almost seems to be coming from the kitchen, maybe the fridge? But I cannot quite pinpoint it.

Please see the link below for a sample of the alarm sound.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/LKWSsMoCtk6ExRfm8

Thank you!
Colin

Comment: I know my refrigerator makes noises when it thinks the water filter needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked our fridge and it's a sub-zero 611, which according to their website does not have a water filter. I was hoping this was the issue. Guess it's back to looking for the noise again.

Comment: It sure sounds like my smoke alarm when I need to replace the batteries. How do you know it’s not the smoke alarm?

Comment: I replaced all the batteries inside my unit. It could be from outside hallway since I do live in an apartment complex. I will check.

Comment: removing the batteries from the smoke alarms makes more sense if you are trying to determine if a smoke alarm is making the noise

Comment: The unit that I have is USI-1204 and it is hardwired in with battery backup. I've replaced the battery and it's still making the sound. I did just notice that the smoke detector itself is from 2004, which needs to be replaced. I wonder if that's the warning sound to replace the entire smoke detector?

Comment: Yes, could be the end-of-life sound. But also on the combination hard-wired / battery versions, if the hard-wired connection is bad, replacing the battery will not fix the alarm problem. I discovered that on mine the hard way. A wire had been poorly connected with a wire nut and came loose in a connection box.

Comment: Could it be a nearby apartment, where owners are out and left smoke detector battery to die? This seems likely, since the volume of the recording was quite low.

Comment: In an apartment, smoke detectors (and their batteries) are normally the responsibility of the building (in the US anyway).  If you think there's a problem let maintenance sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will contact building maintenance.